# Do you know of any download accelerator that can resume partial downloads from wget?

Tags: linux, download, wget, download-manager

I have used `wget` to try to download a big file. After several hours I realized that it would have been better to use a download accelerator. I would not like to discard the significant portion that `wget` has already downloaded. Do you know of any download accelerator that can resume this partial download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [aria2c](http://aria2.sourceforge.net/aria2c.1.html) .. -c option should do the trick (look for word wget in man :))

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered that [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/) can resume the download too. An excellent tutorial can be found at http://tutorials.papamike.ca/pub/lftp.html.